Why is the deployment on to mainnet not happening?
We have been trying for a week to deploy on mainnet and it keeps timing out. Very frustrating, we have investors WAITING.

could you provide further details, for example share the logs output, together with you anchor and solana cli versions. Does deployment work on testnet and devnet clusters?

I'll get back to you on this, Devnet and Testnet is fine, we just can't seem to upload to mainnet. It's a large Web3 package and the guys are trying a manual approach so if they succeed I'll post the details up for reference.

You could try

Using a different API endpoint if you are using the RPC public endpoint
Setting the compute unit and priority fees when deploying,

solana program deploy my_program.so --with-compute-unit-price 1
Set compute unit price for transaction, in increments of 0.000001 lamports per compute unit.

yes and there is also an option to avoid "max retry" error, --max-sign-attempts 1000

Try with version 1.18.12 there are some fixes in there regarding program deploys:
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.18.12/install)"

https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/install
And also what Jimii said :)
